# Apache WEB server still responds to requests used SSLv2 protocol. When SSLv2 protocol was disabled

Tags: https, apache2, mod-ssl

Here is my configuration ...

> SSLProtocol -ALL +SSLv3 TLSv1

but Apache WEB server still responds to requests used SSLv2 protocol.

The following is my test log.( Sorry, I cannot attach image because my reputation is under the 10 )

> SSLv2 Record Layer: Server Hello
> [Version: SSL 2.0 (0x0002)]
> Length: 955
> Handshake Message Type: Server Hello (4)
> Session ID Hit: False
> Certificate Type X.509 Certificate (1)
> Version: SSL 2.0 (0x0002)
> Certificate Length: 928
> Cipher Spec Length: 0
> Connection ID Length: 16
> Certificate blah~blah~
> Connection ID

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The configuration should set as:

```
SSLProtocol= "ALL:-SSLv2"
```

If that does not work also set the cipher suite as:

```
SSLCipherSuite="ALL:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:!SSLv2"
```